# Insert multiple spans inside a shopify liquid template

Tags: jquery, node.js, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I want to add 3 spans at different places as placeholders inside **sections/product-template.liquid** template of Shopify using jquery in NodeJS.

The template looks like this.

```
<div class="product-template__container page-width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="ProductSection-{{ section.id }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product" data-enable-history-state="true">
 <meta itemprop="name" content="{{ product.title }}">
 <meta itemprop="url" content="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}">
</div>

{% if collection %}
 <p class="text-center return-link-wrapper">
  <a href="{{ collection.url }}" class="btn btn--secondary btn--has-icon-before return-link">
    {% include 'icon-arrow-left' %}
    {{ 'products.product.back_to_collection' | t: title: collection.title }}
  </a>
 </p>
{% endif %}

{% unless product == empty %}
 <span id="ProductJson-{{ section.id }}">
  {{ product | json }}
 </span>
{% endunless %}
```

I want to add one span each inside the div, p and span that are shown above.

When I convert the complete string above into jQuery, it gives me access to only the div with class 'product-template__container' but not the other elements which are rendered conditionally inside {%...%}.

How can I add span the conditional elements ?

Comment: What's the page URL that you're trying to run this on? `if collection` will only be `true` if your URL looks something like `myshop.com/collections/favourites/products/coolest-product-ever`

Comment: If there's no `/collections/something` in your current URL, `collection` will be empty, so there won't be anything there

Comment: @Dave B, I am running this code inside the callback function after my app gets installed.

Comment: Right - but what is the actual URL of the page where this code isn't running properly? It could be that the middle block of code doesn't exist on the rendered page (which would be the case when `collection` is not defined in Liquid)

Comment: Oh - and you wouldn't want to put anything inside the ` <span id="ProductJson-{{ section.id }}">` - that span will be parsed directly into a Javascript object, and any HTML inside that span would break the code trying to parse it

Comment: @DaveB, the url is `collections/frontpage/products/coolest-product-ever` . So, `if collection` should be `true`.

Comment: The complete liquid template is returned as a string. When I pass this string to `$(string)`, it shows only `<div class="product-template__container page-width"..>...</div>` but not `{% if collection %}`  or `{% unless product == empty %}` inside it's content. It ignores the latter two sections.

Comment: That is strange - `collection` and `product` should definitely both be truth-y, given that URL. How is "the complete liquid template being returned as a string"? Are you somehow accessing it in a way that would make Shopify try to render the template in a context where either of those could be undefined?  What happens if you wrap that whole section with `{% raw %}` ... `{% endraw %}`, or if you add something like `<h2>Collection:
 {{ collection | json}} / Product: {{ product | json}}</h2>` as a debugging line to make sure those are set?